# What are the best ORMs over SQlite to work with Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, orm

I'm new at iOS Development and I'm looking for an alternative of just SQlite with Objective-C, thanks in advance!

Comment: try with Realm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend this ones:

```
- FMDB 
- chibi-ORM
- sqlitepersistentobjects
```

Additionaly I would recommend

- REALM

This doesn't work with SQLite but, however it is an excellent alternative.